# Is there a similar project to CrossBridge but just using Javascript and not Flash?

Tags: javascript, c++, c, flash, browser

I am working on a application that needs to use C/C++ code on the Web, so googling I found  [CrossBridge](http://adobe-flash.github.io/crossbridge/) which allows me to just do that, but it depends heavily on Flash, I am wondering if there is a counterpart but using just JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

If you can work within the confines of the LLVM, there is [emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki).

Another possibility would be [NaCl](https://developers.google.com/native-client/) within in chrome, that's not javascript as you asked for, but it runs C/C++ in a browser, with limitations.

Comment: Why was this answer unaccepted?

Comment: I am trying to adapt the code of [Foma](https://code.google.com/p/foma/) for the web, I tested it with your suggestions but none of work.

Comment: Ok, that makes good sense. Just seeing it change without explanation gave me pause.